# I need to hide certain aspects of a sharepoint item when printing

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, printing

Particularly I need to hide the save/cancel buttons and some of the images such as the date picker. Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks! :)

Comment: Define a separate print stylesheet.

Comment: Print Stylesheet: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Answer (score 1):

You would want to include a separate stylesheet meant for printing, the syntax being like so: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="nameofsheet.css" type="text/css" media="print" />`. Within it you would want to give the buttons and images you don't wish to display on print a property of `display:none`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a print stylesheet...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

In this stylesheet you can do this for instance...

```
button {
  display: none;
}
```

It is **even better** to have a section in your CSS file like this...

```
@media print {
   button: display: none;
}
```

This will save you an extra http request, because the browser always downloads the print stylesheet, not only when you print.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I added a CSS webpart and inserted the @media code and then changed the SharePoint savebutton to this:<SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server" CssClass="print" ControlMode="Edit" id="savebutton1"/>
But that didn't stop it from printing. I'm sure I am missing something. Currently I can't change the main CSS files because they are locked down where I work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can't you inject the following html in your page <style>@media print { button: display: none; }</style>

Comment: I went back and looked and the webpart is blank except for <style></style> I have no idea what is going on. bleh.

Comment: Can't you store a CSS file in a doc.lib. and reference the CSS file from there using the standard <link /> tag?

Comment: @SaraKcatou Do you have a solution? Can you add a CSS file to a document library maybe?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to any of the CSS or Master page files. My office has it all locked down. I got the content editor web part to keep the style code but all it did was make my save button shorter. It still prints.

Comment: @SaraKcatou Even though you don't have access to the existing CSS files are you able to upload a separate CSS file to a document library? This way you can reference the CSS file in the doclib.

Comment: Ok I found this script online and it does get rid of my save button. However I cannot seem to duplicate it to get rid of the cancel button. It will only do one or the other. <script type="text/javascript">



_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("setValue");

function setValue() {
hideButton("Save");
}

//This function hides a button on the page
function hideButton(valueDef){
var frm = document.forms[0];
for (i=0;i< frm.elements.length;i++) {
if (frm.elements[i].type == "button" && frm.elements[i].value == valueDef) {
frm.elements[i].style.display = "none";
}
}
}</script>

Comment: @SaraKcatou: Does this hide the button when printing?

Comment: It hides it all together, but the save button in the ribbon is still active so people can still save.